# R filter top3 records (latest 3 months records) by group

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

i'm doing some data transformation that require to filter top 3 records (last 3 months's records from max date) by group. Below are the concept.
[image]

I want to filter out latest 3 months records by id, the ultimate objective is to do some aggregation based on the latest 3 months records by id.

***note: the highlighted orange colour indicate no value (therefore selected by last 3 observation might not work for this case)***

```
# Sample dateset
df <- data.frame(id=c('A06','A06','A06','A06','A06','A08','A08','A08','A168','A168'), 
             date=c("31/10/2018","31/12/2018","28/2/2018","30/4/2018","31/5/2018","31/7/2017","31/8/2017","30/9/2017","31/10/2016","31/12/2016"), 
             value=c(20,8,2,3,7,15,4,1,1,5))
```

I did tried select last N rows using below code, but it wont work for my case, since empty value might exists between last 3 months records (example: highlighted orange colour on above diagram). **Therefore, i think the filter should based on date**

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number() >= (n() - 2))
```

Expected results

[image]

Any idea how can i filter it? prefer `dplyr`, `lubridate` packages

Comment: Hi @A. Suliman & @Sotos , i did tried the mark as duplicated `link` but it's abit different from my case. In addition i had edit my question with clearer explaination, could you guys reopen my question?

Comment: Date linked to value, I think you need the last 3 obs and they are !=' '. Try `df %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(tail(row_number(value!=''), 3))`. To reach SO user you need to mention each user in separte comment. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @A.Suliman thanks for reply, i solved the problem on my own after brain storm awhile, i'm using `df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(between(date, max(date) - months(2), max(date)))`. Any way thanks for your helping hand!